# Xcode 4 Code Sense don't show class name on right hand side of an equal statement

Tags: autocomplete, xcode4, codesense

On Xcode 4, when I tried to create a variable by its class factory method, say:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xxx"];
```

Code Sense works fine on left hand side, but when I type "nsa" on right hand side it won't show NSArray. This problem happens on all classes in Xcode 4, can it be fixed?

thanks,
Kelvin

UPDATE: This problem has been resolved in Xcode 4.0.2. However, we still need to type the "[" first in order to show the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Your first stop should be to report this at http://bugreport.apple.com but one work-around would be to open the Organizer and select the Projects tab, then select your project and click the Delete... button to the right of the Derived Data path. Confirm it then close and re-open the project for good measure. This will force Xcode to re-index the project.

Comment: I also think its a bug of XCode 4, but rebuilding project index seems doesn't solve the problem. Because this problem exists for all foundation classes, not only my own classes...